# Facebook Request 2.0 apprequests and exclude_ids

Tags: javascript, facebook

Is it possible to exclude certain Facebook IDs in the apprequests dialog like the exclude_ids parameter in the old fb:multi-friend-selector?
I know about the filters property, but it seems not sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE:
Exclude Ids are now supported with Requests 2.0.  You can pass a comma delimited list of UIDs with:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'Hello World',
  exclude_ids: '499802852,499804089'
  }, requestCallback);
```

Docs are at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Comment: Currently, the documentation claims that the exclude_ids parameter should be an array, not a comma-separated string-of-IDs.

Comment: this is not working. i get an error:

`Error
param exclude_ids must be an array.`

Answer (score 1):

It should be an array, example:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Hello World',
    exclude_ids: ['499802852','499804089'],
}, requestCallback);
```